# Auto deduct money from the paypal transaction to send it to app owner

Tags: ios, cordova, paypal

I have a scenario, I am working in the phone gap iOS application which able a user to buy and sell a commodity. Take three persons A(Owner of the app),B(Seller),C(Buyer).

B wants to sale a commodity and C want to buys it. C agreed upon a common point and proceed with the payment. Now when the C pays for the commodity i want to shift 2% of the amount to  the A account and rest of the payment to the B.

I am aware this is done over the websites and there are plenty of examples. I want to know few things:

1. Is it possible in phone gap application, does paypal sdk allow to do so.
2. how could i do the two transaction in one single go, in case i need to do both the things manually.
3. Is this thing can be automated or this will be handled manually at the back end.

[Here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap) is the link for the phone gap plugin that i am using for app.

If anyone could guide me to any doc which explains this or any helping material that will be a great help. I have been reading and searching over net but could not get any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  It's definitely possible as it's just a matter of making API calls.  The SDK should handle it for you, but if not you could always build the requests yourself.

2)  You could do either a parallel payment (where the payer would see both receivers during checkout) or a chained payment (where the payer would only see the primary receiver during checkout.)

Most people doing this sort of thing like to hide the split, so I'll assume you want to do a chained payment.  You'll make a request to the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) with a primary receiver set to the seller and the secondary receiver set to you.

You'll set the primary receiver amount the full amount and the secondary receiver to their amount accordingly.  For example, if $100 is paid the primary receiver amount would be $100 (not $98) and the secondary receiver would be $2.

I would definitely recommend reviewing the [Adaptive Payments documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) which has a lot of detail about chained payments and how it all works.

3).  Both transactions will automatically happen when the payer completes the checkout.

Comment: Thank you very much for this info. I have vision now to start with. thanks again